# Protocol Oriented Programming

Tags: ios, swift, model, protocols

As we transition our brains from `Object Oriented Programming` to `Protocol Oriented Programming` how can I do the following ?

let's say I have a `JSON` object representing `Model` has {created_time,updated_time,type,...} and those values are common in 5 Model objects.

is it right to make a protocol contains all the above properties like the following

```
protocol xxx {
   var type : String { get }
   var updatedTime : String { get }
   var createdTime : String { get }
   //...//
}
```

and then all the 5 structs conform to this protocol

Comment: upvote for your question..how do you know about these all?? :)

Comment: One thing I'd recommend, is to drop the habit of making everything a String. It's convenient, but is almost guaranteed to cause problems later. A "time" should either be a TimeInterval, or a Date. Using Strings everywhere seems to be what happens when people come from dynamically-typed languages, but it isn't a healthy habit to keep up in the long-term.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that's a perfectly good solution. The alternative would be having a base class with those properties and have all five of those models inherit from the base class, but there's no particular reason to use inheritance here.

A protocol is just a "contract" that guarantees a class has certain properties or behavior. To me, your example here feels very "contractual."

By contrast, inheritance implies a "is-a" relationship (e.g. a Ford is-a car). To me, this feels more like a contract than an "is-a" case. Of course, neither choice is wrong, but think your protocol idea here is good.

Comment: since I am  using structs I cannot use classes. because a struct doesn't have inheritance

Comment: Right, so with structs, using a protocol like this is definitely the right choice. I thought I would contrast the protocol-oriented approach with an inheritance approach one might use with classes.

Comment: the problem is it will be very redundant since I need to make the same 5 properties in every struct

Comment: There isn't really a way around that with protocols unfortunately. Protocols only promise that a particular behavior will exist, it doesn't do any of the implementing for you. Avoiding that sort of redundancy is possible with inheritance, but (as you pointed out) Swift doesn't support struct inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of Protocol Oriented Programming Swift 2 has protocol extensions which allow default implementations. This also replaces many cases where you would use a superclass instead.

In this case:

```
// extension of your example protocol
extension xxx {
   var type : String { return "a type" }
   var updatedTime : String { return "00:00" }
   var createdTime : String { return "00:00" }
   //...//
}

// struct which conforms to it
struct Astruct: xxx {}

// using the properties
Astruct().type
Astruct().updatedTime
```

if all properties and methods have a default implementation by the protocol extension you don't have to provide any yourself. However you can "override" them only by implementing them.

So you're decision is right and you should use protocols as often as possible.

The only big drawback is that there is no `super` where you can explicitly call the default implementations. A workaround (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31797887/4780031)) would require a superclass which makes the protocol almost redundant.

Comment: but what if all the properties don't have a default implementation ? i.e: let's say I have  `var iD: String! { get }` property in the protocol all the structs that implement this protocol must have `let _id : String!` and later on `var iD : String { get { return _id } }` imagine you have like 5 properties in the Protocol and 5 structs. It will be a huge redundant. @Qbyte

Comment: @Bobj-C Why do all the types which implement the protocol have to have a `let _id:String!` and `var iD: String! { get }` at the same time? If you have a specific problem explain it further please.

Comment: let's say the init of the struct as the following `init(dictionary: JSON){...}` so if I want to read the value `id` and put it inside `_id` it will be like `_id = JSON["id"]`. and because this struct implement protocol it must have `var iD:String { get { return _id } }`

Comment: @Bobj-C You don't have to have an `_id` variable because a `var iD: String` variable in your struct is sufficient to conform to it. It doesn't require a computed property.

Comment: you are right I didnt notice that before Thank you :)